# openzeppline 'npm i @openzeppline/contracts' error

Tags: reactjs, hardhat, openzeppelin

I am creating a react app, I am facing these errors while I ran.

```
npm i @openzeppline/contracts
```

Errors I am getting, I have tried many solutions but it's not working.

```
 @openzeppline/contracts@*' is not in this registry.
 GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@openzeppline%2fcontracts - Not found
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are misspelled the npm package name. openzeppelin instead of openzeppeline.

```
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
```